# How to unregister Group for certain user in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

[image]

I am going to customize the Built-In Django Authentication and Authorization page.  In my case I have 2 levels administrators. The lower level administrators can only add/remove users other than add/remove groups, therefore I am planning to hide the `Group` from them.

`admin.site.unregister(Group)` works but it unregister Group for all admins.  Does anyone know which class should I customize?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to remove Group from admin page, you have to customize all related classes to achieve this. Read more here [django admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/) to understand Django's admin page better. Hope it helps.